# What are the signs your (stolen) phone has been wiped/hard reset?

Tags: lost-phone, remote-wipe, android-device-manager

I had my 2-week-old HTC One stolen. Unfortunately, I was not aware of the Android Device Manager or the ability to turn on remote wipe functionality (nor I had any remote tracking/wiping apps installed). My phone had a lot of private stuff on it. I really dread this stuff being in someone else's hands.

Since the theft to restrict access to my private information, I logged out all other Google sessions, changed Google account password, switched 2-step verification to another device, revoked access permissions to apps on my stolen phone and the phone. However, the best case scenario for protecting my information would be to wipe the phone.

I would like to know the following:

1. Having changed Google account password and done all of the above, will I still be able to push apps to the phone through Google Play (e.g., Plan B or Android Lost)?
2. Having effectively stopped my phone from syncing with Google (change passwords etc), if it is switched on with data connection will it still show up on Android Device Manager?
3. Is there a way - taking into consideration all the stuff I have done to prevent the thief from logging into my apps/account - to find out if the phone has been wiped? e.g., Android Device Manager will stop showing it as registered?

Answer (score 3):

1. No, as the device will require the new password before it will successfully log in to the Play Store app to download any apps.
2. Again, No as it will not send any data to Google because you've changed your password.
3. I'm not aware of any way to find out this information. Unfortunately by changing your password and ending sessions there is no way to communicate with the device using your Google account.